# Seasonality (as in seasons) statistical analysis

Tags: correlation, seasonality

I want to perform a statistical analysis on scores obtained through medical exams, correlating them to the season (as in spring, summer, fall, winter) when they were obtained. How do you suggest to proceed?

Consider that:

- Because seasons have slight different length, I can not divide years by quarters.
- I do not want to make predictions on future outcomes.
- I only want to determine if and how much a season correlates with higher/lower scores
- I have many years to analyze: can I begin from the date I want if I terminate the analysis on the same date n years after it?
- The difference between years is not very important

I read ([What statistical test is appropriate to answer hypotheses on seasonal and spatial differences?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279873/what-statistical-test-is-appropriate-to-answer-hypotheses-on-seasonal-and-spatia) and [How to prove statistical significance between the 4 seasons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56481/how-to-prove-statistical-significance-between-the-4-seasons)), but I would like other opinions.